# HTML tables border not disapearing when set to 0

Tags: html, html-table, border

The problem that I am having is while designing an email to be sent to users the border of the HTML table is not disappearing even though it is set to 0 and so leaves horrible white lines through areas which are menu to be solid blue colors, below is my HTML code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="889" border="0" >
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table width="882" border="0" bordercolor="#0099FF">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#0099FF">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#0099FF">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#0099FF">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">content</td>
            <td bgcolor="#0099FF">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add cellspacing="0" to your second table:

```
<table width="882" border="0" bordercolor="#0099FF" cellspacing="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably *cellspacing="0"* fixes these lines?